# Why is it that a Matrix transpose times itself is a scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the following image, you can see the illustration of the question:

[image]

Comment: $x_i$ is the $i$th *column* of the matrix $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x$ is a column vector of length $m$, $xx^T$ is an $m\times m$ matrix, not a scalar.

It's a scalar when $x$ is a row vector.

Comment: I missed that. thanks.